# what is the difference between human and human being?

Tags: word-choice

i am an English teacher and i usually come across a great deal of questions related to words, the other day a student of mine asked me the difference between the words **human** and **human being** but to be honest i had no suitable answer for him, i have also asked this question from a couple of teachers but they unfortunately came up with no convincing answer so i wanted to know what the difference between these two  words is.

Comment: Being a human English teacher, shouldn't you be capitalising the pronoun ***I*** in your post?

Comment: Please take help in composing the post. Capitalize the first person singular. Use a period at the end of a sentence, not a comma. This is an advanced Q&A site.

Comment: Have you checked some good dictionaries?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/human

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I thing the only difference is that **human being** is singular form and referrers to only one human and the word **human beings** is the plural form talking about a the entire species of human.

Comment: Isn't the question about the difference between ***human*** and ***human being***? Oh, I see the OP has since edited the question.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you could fix your answer.